# Cant control the Numerical variable trigger condition with the OnClickEvent. OnClickEvent triggering multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, events

first time post here. a beginner.

What I'm trying to do here is that:

I'm trying to display an image of a silhouette of a person. And with every click, the current image fades out and another image of the same person (different position/location) fades in. kind of like an animation except very bare bones.

I made a variable that supposedly controls when certain images fade in or out(var currentscene).The button that calls the function covers the entire page and is invisible because I want the animation to move frame by frame with a click anywhere from the page.

('stand' is an image of a boy standing and 'sit' is an image of a boy sitting) edit: in the example it becomes squareblue and squarered.

(fade-in and fade-out are classes that I add to the image so the transition triggers)

And yet the problem is that a single click will fade in both pictures, as if the number on the variable (currentscene) doesn't matter or the onclick event registered infinite number of clicks or something like that.

**Im trying to make the blue square fade in on the first click and the blue fade out and the red fade in on the second click of the button.**

If there is a fix to this that would be helpful. If there is a whole another way to do what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm all ears. Although I've tried looking into arrays and EventListeners but I haven't been successful.

heres a recreation of the problem:

```js
var currentscene = 0;

function next() {
  currentscene++;
  if (currentscene = 1) {
    var element = document.getElementById("blue");
    element.classList.add("fade-in");
  }
  if (currentscene = 2) {
    var element = document.getElementById("blue");
    element.classList.add("fade-out");

    var element = document.getElementById("red");
    element.classList.add("fade-in");
  }
}
```

```css
.squareblue {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.squarered {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut ease 2s
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn ease 2s
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div2 id="blue" class="squareblue"></div2>
<div2 id="red" class="squarered"></div2>

<button class="button" onclick="next()">next</button>
```

Comment: Probably need to place `currentscene++;` last as you are querying the *current scene*. But post some running code, so we can reproduce the problem... [reprex]

Comment: thanks for answering. took a while to recreate it and format it correctly but i edited onto the post.